# How can I allocate and re-use a C struct from Haskell?

Tags: c, haskell, ffi, allegro, hsc2hs

In particular, I'm trying to learn Haskell's foreign function interface by writing a binding to the Allegro game library. In Allegro's native C, the main event loop looks something like this:

```
// initialize event struct
ALLEGRO_EVENT event;

// main loop
while (running) {
    if (al_get_next_event(event_queue, &event)) {
        // process event here ...
    }
}
```

Using ghc and hsc2hs, I can write a foreign function call like:

```
foreign import ccall "allegro5/allegro.h al_get_next_event"
    alGetNextEvent :: EventQueue -> Ptr (Event) -> IO (CInt)
```

where `EventQueue` is a pointer to an opaque structure and `Event` is a `Storable` instance based off of C's `ALLEGRO_EVENT`.

Ideally, for the user-facing Haskell function, I would like to have a type signature like

```
getNextEvent :: EventQueue -> Maybe Event
```

which would abstract away initializing the `ALLEGRO_EVENT` struct and boolean return value.

My question is, how should I write this function to maximize memory efficiency? I could malloc a new pointer to `Event` inside the method and use that, but since I'm working with C-based data, I want to make sure I'm re-using existing space and not constantly allocating new structs. I also want to avoid having the user malloc the struct and pass it in to every call.

Any advice?

Comment: There are some partial bindings here: https://github.com/chrra/allegro-raw. Not sure if it's useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, if it is locally scoped data, you would use

- [alloca](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Foreign-Marshal-Alloc.html)

If the data has longer scope,

- [mallocForeignPtr](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.3.0.0/doc/html/Foreign-ForeignPtr.html#4)

is a good choice, since it is very fast, you can attach finalizers, and you don't have to clean up on your own.

The GHC runtime takes care of maximally reusing space for you, so there's not too much of a need to worry about efficiency by e.g. pinning a mutable memory buffer in place. Just let the GC take care of things.